# Custom workflow - log who in a group completed a task

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, workflow-history

I have created an approval workflow using SharePoint Designer 2013.  Using Start a Task Process, it assigns a task to a group.  Only one person in the group has to approve/complete the task.  I have that set up correctly.  How do I log to history which person approved/completed it?